SwiperJS не работает на мобильном телефоне правильно, но на ПК все отлично
В общем верстал раньше этим слайдеров все было идеально, но тут решил посмотреть все слайдеры которые верстал на телефоне и вышла такая вот проблема: что на ПК при 1920 до 320 ширине все нормально работает, а вот если зайти на сайт через телефон слайдер отказывается работать.


Причин может быть очень много. Что бы разобраться надо как минимум добавить сюда свой код
